# Cholesky factorization in least squares

Tags: linear-algebra

In system of linear equations , we have AX=B. In order to solve it using least squares method, we do the following:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        A^TAX=A^TB\\
        X =(A^TA)^{-1} A^TB \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

If we use cholesky decomposition, A can be expressed as

$$
A=LL^T
$$

Then is it possible that

$$
X=(LL^T)^{-1}A^TB 
$$

If yes, kindly explain the derivation as I am not able to understand line no. 11 in the given algorithm.
[image: 1]]

Comment: It is the matrix $\mathbf A^\top\mathbf A$ that you should be decomposing since it is positive (semi)definite, and not $\mathbf A$.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Thanks for your input. Btw why you gave a comment , why not a separate answer.